# ExtJS - disable/enable elements on combo change

Tags: javascript, extjs

The title says much about it. I will pass you an example below:

```
let scalesField = {
    xtype: 'combo',
    name: property.name + 'scale',
    listeners: {
        change: function (combo, selectedValue) {
            // here would be some logic
            // Tried with:
            Ext.Array.each(possibleValues, function (single, index) {
                possibleValues[index].disabled = true;
                if (possibleValues[index].scale_id === selectedValue) {
                    possibleValues[index].disabled = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

if (possible_values.length > 0) {
    Ext.Array.each(possible_values, function (single, index) {
        fields.push({
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
            fieldLabel: possible_values[index].name,
            name: possible_values[index].name,
            labelWidth: 100,
        });
    });
}
```

Variable 'possible_values' contain all possible checkboxes as are defined in the 'if' block. I want to disable or enable checkboxes depending on what option user choose in combo(select option dropdown).

After running code as below I can see in the console that property disabled is changed but it does not apply to a view.

How to solve this in `ExtJS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like below:-

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('checkboxfield[name=' + possibleValues[index].name + ']')[0].setDisabled(true /*/false*/ );
```